# Union join two tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to a filtered table (tableA) with another table(tableB).

The code I used for getting the result for tableA

```
select c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
from conversation c
right join (select * from conversation_tag
where tag = 'atlas-interest') as a
on a.conversation_id = c.id;
```

tableA

[image]

tableB

[image]

I want to outer join these two tables by "email". However, I keep getting syntax problem
My code

```
select * from contact con
LEFT JOIN (select c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
from conversation c
right join (select * from conversation_tag
where tag = 'atlas-interest') as a
on a.conversation_id = c.id)) ON con.email = cc.email
UNION 
select * from con
RIGHT JOIN (select c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
from conversation c
right join (select * from conversation_tag
where tag = 'atlas-interest') as a
on a.conversation_id = c.id)) on con.email = cc.email;
```

My another question is, the code is easy to become messy in nested select Is there any way that I can save tableA as a variable and just call the variable while joining tableB?
I found this method `SET @v1 := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_rating);` but it seems it can only save one column at a time.

Comment: Define a view with the nested select.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query can be simplified to:

```
select c.id, ct.conversation_id, ct.tag, c.email, c.created_at
from conversation c join
     conversation_tag ct
     on ct.conversation_id = c.id
where ct.tag = 'atlas-interest';
```

I doubt you have any `conversation_id` in `conversation_tag` that don't match back.

Next you want a full outer join on `con`.  For this, gather all the emails and use `left join`s:

```
select ct.*, con.*
from ((select c.email
       from con c
      ) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select c.email
       from conversation c join
            conversation_tag ct
            on ct.conversation_id = c.id
       where ct.tag = 'atlas-interest'
      )
     ) e left join
     con
     on e.email = con.email left join
     (select c.id, ct.conversation_id, ct.tag, c.email, c.created_at
      from conversation c join
           conversation_tag ct
           on ct.conversation_id = c.id
      where ct.tag = 'atlas-interest'
     ) ct
     on e.email = ct.email;
```

The `left join`/`right join`/`union` hack is just not very related to a real `full join`.  It removes duplicates, for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to remove duplicate, is there any way that I can keep duplicated rows ?

Comment: @Osca . . . This does not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `cc` aliases for the subqueries.

```
SELECT * FROM contact con
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
     FROM conversation c
     RIGHT JOIN (
           SELECT * FROM conversation_tag
           WHERE tag = 'atlas-interest') AS a
     ON a.conversation_id = c.id
) AS cc ON con.email = cc.email
UNION 
     SELECT c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
     FROM conversation c
     RIGHT JOIN (
           SELECT * FROM conversation_tag
           WHERE tag = 'atlas-interest') AS a
     ON a.conversation_id = c.id
) AS cc ON con.email = cc.email
```

To avoid having to repeat the subquery, you could define a view:

```
CREATE VIEW atlas_conversations AS
SELECT c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
FROM conversation c
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM conversation_tag
    WHERE tag = 'atlas-interest'
) AS a ON a.conversation_id = c.id;
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM contact AS con
LEFT JOIN atlas_conversations AS cc ON con.email = cc.email
UNION
SELECT *
FROM contact AS con
RIGHT JOIN atlas_conversations AS cc ON con.email = cc.email
```

Comment: Thank you. For the first code, I got error `Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias` . The Create View code has error on line two `select` statement. However, if I remove `CREATE VIEW atlas_conversations`, then the code can run normally.

Comment: You had an extra `)` after each subquery.

Comment: And I had an extra `;` at the end of the view.

Comment: I was missing the `AS` keyword

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. As to your first query ...

```
select c.id, a.conversation_id, a.tag, c.email, c.created_at
from conversation c
right join (select * from conversation_tag
where tag = 'atlas-interest') as a
on a.conversation_id = c.id;
```

We don't usually use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, because they are harder to read then left outer joins. After all you select `conversation_tag` rows with `tag = 'atlas-interest'` and outer join their `conversation` rows. But why do you even outer join? How could there possibly be a `conversation_tag` without a related `conversation`? That would mean a broken database (due to a missing foreign key).

This said, your query should simply be:

```
select *
from conversation_tag ct
join conversation c on c.id = ct.conversation_id
where ct.tag = 'atlas-interest';
```